# Highlighting all matched keyword in strings in case insensitive manner and preserve case in the returned tex

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to highlight/mark all occurrences of a string in another string. 
i searched and find this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php#87417

but minute after that i have found bug/issue in it (may be i am wrong too)

however here is my code:

```
<?php

$strMain = 'This is cOloR One, this is CoLOR two and third color this one!';
$strFind = 'color';

echo highlightStr($strMain, $strFind, '#FF0000');

function highlightStr($haystack, $needle, $highlightColorValue)
{
     // return $haystack if there is no highlight color or strings given, nothing to do.
    if (strlen($highlightColorValue) < 1 || strlen($haystack) < 1 || strlen($needle) < 1) {
        return $haystack;
    }
    preg_match_all("/$needle+/i", $haystack, $matches);
    if (is_array($matches[0]) && count($matches[0]) >= 1) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
            $haystack = str_replace($match, '<span style="color:'.$highlightColorValue.';">'.$match.'</span>', $haystack);
        }
    }
    return $haystack;
}   
?>
```

if you run the code, then you will see the issue. Result will be even worse if you search for a single letter like 'o'..

so, is there any better/perfect solution to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) instead :

```
<?php

$strMain = 'This is cOloR One, this is CoLOR two and third color this one!';
$strFind = 'color';

echo highlightStr($strMain, $strFind, '#FF0000');

function highlightStr($haystack, $needle, $highlightColorValue)
{
     // return $haystack if there is no highlight color or strings given, nothing to do.
    if (strlen($highlightColorValue) < 1 || strlen($haystack) < 1 || strlen($needle) < 1) {
        return $haystack;
    }
    $haystack = preg_replace("/($needle+)/i", '<span style="color:'.$highlightColorValue.';">'.'$1'.'</span>', $haystack);
    return $haystack;
}   
?>
```

output :

```
This is <span style="color:#FF0000;">cOloR</span> One, this is <span style="color:#FF0000;">CoLOR</span> two and third <span style="color:#FF0000;">color</span> this one!
```

demo here : https://eval.in/147973

Answer (score 1):

Use an `strtr()` and it will replace all occurences as you are looking for..

```
<?php

$strMain = 'This is cOloR One, this is CoLOR two and third color this one!';
$strFind = 'color';

echo highlightStr($strMain, $strFind, '#FF0000');

function highlightStr($haystack, $needle, $highlightColorValue)
{
    // return $haystack if there is no highlight color or strings given, nothing to do.
    if (strlen($highlightColorValue) < 1 || strlen($haystack) < 1 || strlen($needle) < 1) {
        return $haystack;
    }
    $repList = array();
    preg_match_all("/$needle+/i", $haystack, $matches);
    //print_r($matches);
    if (is_array($matches[0]) && count($matches[0]) >= 1) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
            $repList[$match]='<span style="color:'.$highlightColorValue.';">'.$match.'</span>';
        }
    }
    $haystack = strtr($haystack,$repList);
    return $haystack;
}
?>
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

[image]

Now, if you changed your `$strFind = 'color';` to `$strFind = 'o';` , you would expect the below result..

[image]

Comment: @hwnd, I know did you see he mentioned _Result will be even worse if you search for a single letter like 'o'.._ , so you should use `strtr()` for this.

Comment: I overlooked it. My fault.